# How to dynamically add listheaders and listcells in ZK

Tags: listbox, zk, dynamically-generated, listitem, zul

I am totally new in ZK. I need to create **N** listheaders and **N** listcells in my zul file. But I do not know how to do it from my java controller and I am **not** using MVVM.

The problem would be something like:

```java
   @Wire
   private Window idWindow;

   private Listheader header;
   private Listcell item1;

  @Override
    public void onCreate(Event event) {

    header.setLabel("laaaa");// It would set just one header but I can have many (N headers) and same for items

   }
```

```html
<zk>
  <window id="idWindow" title="nameWindow" apply="controller.java" border="normal" closable="true" sizable="true" maximizable="true" maximized="true" height="85%" width="150%" style="overflow:auto;">
    <!-- CONTINUES -->

   <listbox id="mainList" hflex="1" vflex="1">
      <listhead>
          <listheader id="header" label="A" />
          <listheader id="header1" label="B"  /> 
          <listheader id="header2" label="C"  />
          ....
          <listheader id="headerN" label="N" />             
      </listhead>
      <listitem>
          <listcell id="item1" label="A"/>
          <listcell id="item2" label="B"/>
          <listcell id="item3" label="C"/>
          ....
          <listcell id="itemN" label="D"/>
      </listitem>
     </listbox>

   <!-- CONTINUES -->
    </window>
</zk>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave the `listhead` empty in the zul, wire it into your controller and create the `listheaders` there. The important step is to ask the `listbox` for its `listhead`, and append the `listheaders` to it. For the cells, give your `listbox` a renderer that creates them for each item if you use a model to give your list data.

Your zul will be much shorter:

```
<zk>
    <window ... >
        <listbox id="mainList" hflex="1" vflex="1">
            <listhead />
        </listbox>
    </window>
</zk>
```

Then in your controller, you create the header in `doAfterCompose` and attach the renderer:

```
@Wire
private Listbox mainList;

@Override  // This method should be specified by a composer super class
public void doAfterCompose(Component comp)throws Exception
{
    super.doAfterCompose(comp);

    mainList.setModel(someModelWithYourData);

    // create listheaders (manually/in for-loop/based on data...)
    Listhead head = mainList.getListhead();
    head.appendChild(new Listheader("A"));
    ...

    // attach renderer
    mainList.setItemRenderer(new ListitemRenderer<Object>() // use proper data type instead of Object
    {
        @Override
        public void render(Listitem item, Object data, int index)
            throws Exception
        {
            item.appendChild(new Listcell("a"));
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

There is also an example on zk's developer sites: https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/MVC/View/Renderer/Listbox_Renderer

In case you cannot use a model, you could also append the `listitems` in the zul or in the controller, and then create the listcells:

```
for (Component child : mainList.getChildren()) 
{
    if (child instanceof Listitem) 
    {
        Listitem item = (Listitem) child;
        // do the same as in the renderer
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works, I could not use with model but the other way worked.